# Discussing a better approach for Leetcode Question Minimum Difficulty of a Job Schedule

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, space-complexity

You want to schedule a list of jobs in d days. Jobs are dependent (i.e To work on the i-th job, you have to finish all the jobs j where 0 <= j < i).

You have to finish at least one task every day. The difficulty of a job schedule is the sum of difficulties of each day of the d days. The difficulty of a day is the maximum difficulty of a job done in that day.

Given an array of integers jobDifficulty and an integer d. The difficulty of the i-th job is jobDifficulty[i].

Return the minimum difficulty of a job schedule. If you cannot find a schedule for the jobs return -1.

```
Input: jobDifficulty = [6,5,4,3,2,1], d = 2
Output: 7
Explanation: First day you can finish the first 5 jobs, total difficulty = 6.
Second day you can finish the last job, total difficulty = 1.
The difficulty of the schedule = 6 + 1 = 7
```

I have the following solution for the above problem:

```
from functools import lru_cache
class Solution:
    def minDifficulty(self, jobDifficulty: List[int], d: int) -> int:
        @lru_cache(None)
        def oneDayDifficulty(start, end):
            if start + 1 == end:
                return jobDifficulty[start]
            mid = (start + end) // 2
            return max(oneDayDifficulty(start, mid), oneDayDifficulty(mid, end))       
        @lru_cache(None)
        def dp(nextTask, days):
            if days == 1:
                return oneDayDifficulty(0, nextTask)
            res = float("inf")
            for startTask in range(days - 1, nextTask):
                res = min(res, dp(startTask, days - 1) + oneDayDifficulty(startTask, nextTask))
            return res
        res = dp(len(jobDifficulty), d)
        return -1 if res == float('inf') else res
```

I'm not sure what would be the time and space complexity, is it going to be O(d*n^2)?
Also do you have a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

We can have `O(d * n * log n)`. Let `dp[i][d]` represent the best choice for the `i`th task assigned to day `d`. Then:

```
dp[i][d] ->
  min (
    max(A[j..i]) + dp[j-1][d-1]
  ) for d - 1 ≤ j ≤ i
```

We can store all `dp[j][d]` we have seen so far in a binary search tree ordered by `A[j]`, with the added decoration of the minimum `dp[j-1][d-1]` associated with any node in the left subtree and `A[j] + dp[j-1][d-1]` associated with any node in the right subtree; along with the `j` it pairs with. When we get to `A[i]`, we look up its position in the tree, keeping track of the minimum `A[j] + dp[j-1][d-1]` associated with any node higher than it, and the minimum `dp[j-1][d-1]` associated with any node equal or lower than it. Then our choice becomes:

```
dp[i][d] ->
  min (
    // A[i] is the first value on day d
    A[i] + dp[i-1][d-1],
    // A[i] would not affect this one
    A[j_higher] + dp[j_higher-1][d-1],
    // A[i] becomes the max for this one
    A[i] + dp[j_eq_or_lower-1][d-1]
  )
  where j_higher is the one paired with the minimum A[j] + dp[j-1][d-1]
  associated with a higher A[j], and j_eq_or_lower is the one paired
  with the minimum dp[j-1][d-1] associated with a lower or equal A[j]
```

Inserting in, updating the decoration, and lookup in the tree in `O(log n)`, and we perform it `O(n)` times for each `d`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Time Complexity By [รยקคгรђשค](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6741053/%e0%b8%a3%e0%b8%a2%d7%a7%e0%b8%84%d0%b3%e0%b8%a3%d1%92%d7%a9%e0%b8%84)

> The time complexity is O(d*N^2). There are N*d states and work for
> each state is O(N) at the most.

- The same thing, implemented maybe a bit simple:

```
class Solution:
    def minDifficulty(self, nums, d):
        @lru_cache(None)
        def depth_first_search(i, d):
            if d == 1:
                return max(nums[i:])
            res, max_days = float('inf'), 0
            for j in range(i, len(nums) - d + 1):
                max_days = max(max_days, nums[j])
                res = min(res, max_days + depth_first_search(j + 1, d - 1))
            return res

        return -1 if len(nums) < d else depth_first_search(0, d)
```

Comment: The time complexity is `O(d*N^2)`. There are `N*d` states and work for each state is `O(N)` at the most.

Answer (score 0):

We can do in `O(d*N)` time complexity with `O(N)` space, with the use of stack.

**Explanation:**

**dp formulation:**

The formulation is little different than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541503/6741053). Since we can compute cost of maximum difficulty found so far on current day `d` using stack.

```
dp[i][d] -  represent minimum difficulty that can be achieved considering d days and first i jobs.
```

**Recurrence:**

There are 3 scenarios:

1. `ith` job is the only job on day d and rest all jobs were completed before day `d`.
2. we try adding to current day and see if `A[i]` has more difficulty than any previous higher difficulty job `j` already completed on present day `d`
3. there is some higher difficulty job `j` we saw previously on present day `d`.

---

```
dp[i][d] = min( A[i] + dp[i-1][d-1], // ith job is the only job on day d 
                A[i] + (dp[j][d] - A[j]), // or we try adding to current day and see if A[i] has more difficulty than any previous higher difficulty job j already completed on present day
                dp[j][d] // or there is some higher difficulty job `j` we saw previously on present day `d`.
              )
```

**C++ Implementation:**

We maintain stack to compute highest difficulty job `j` seen so far. Also as we see in the recurrence we only need values of previous day to compute values of current day, so we save space there.

```
int minDifficulty(vector<int>& A, int D) {
    int jobs = A.size();
    if (jobs < D) return INT_MAX ; // impossible to do atleast 1 job everyday
    int max_difficulty = *max_element(A.begin(), A.end()) + 1;
    vector<int> prv_day(jobs, max_difficulty), curr_day(jobs);
    for (int days = 0; days < D; ++days) {
        vector<int> stack;
        for (int i = days; i < jobs; i++) {
            curr_day[i] = i > 0 ? prv_day[i - 1] + A[i] : A[i]; // start fresh day with first job as ith
            while (!stack.empty() && A[stack.back()] <= A[i]) {
                int j = stack.back(); stack.pop_back();
                curr_day[i] = min(curr_day[i], curr_day[j] - A[j] + A[i]); // or we try extending and see if A[i] has more difficulty than any previous job j on present day 
            }
            if (!stack.empty()) {
                curr_day[i] = min(curr_day[i], curr_day[stack.back()]); // or there is some higher difficulty job we saw previously
            }
            stack.push_back(i);
        }
        swap(prv_day, curr_day);
    }
    return prv_day[jobs - 1];
}
```

**Time complexity:**

For each day we take `O(N)` time to compute. So time complexity is `O(d*N)`. The items in stack are pushed and popped at most `O(N)` times.

**Extra Space complexity:**

`O(N)` to store current and previous states and `O(N)` for stack.